# Stream gulp-filter mistake

Tags: gulp, gulp-filter

```
.pipe( gulp.dest( 'D:/path/to/project/' ) )
.pipe( filter( './**/*.css' ) )
.pipe( browserSync.stream() )
```

I have an error on this part of the code. Files are created but the code is not compiled after `filter`.